# How to move a php variable through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a complex website so var but I am having a tiny problem with moving a php variable `$dlink` through an ajax request.

Image of Code: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/237505447337263104/360125398333390848/unknown.png
 So on page 1 the variable is created and it is called on page 4, but it comes back as undefined. So I tried to a method I found:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".downlink").click(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr("id");
        link = link.replace('link-','');
        var path = '<php? echo $dlink; ?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: "../temp/ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'link': link,
                'path': path,
            },
            success: function(result){
                $("body").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But this is also not working. The middle two pages of code are a template that I need tons of pages to read to hard coding is not desired.

Comment: Simply you can use something like `var path = <?php echo $dlink; ?>;`

Comment: That took me three hours... Than you so much for finding my derp.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a typo `<php?` -> `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

I find it weird you are embedding PHP code in a JavaScript context. You could do some thing like say.. When the page is loading, echo a JavaScript variable holding the value

```
    <?php
         echo "<script> d_link =" .  $dlink ."  </script>";
    ?>
```

Then from your jquery handler you could do

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".downlink").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("id");
    link = link.replace('link-','');
    var path = d_link;  //just reference the variable here
    $.ajax({
        url: "../temp/ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'link': link,
            'path': path,
        },
        success: function(result){
            $("body").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

});